# Cannot Connect to Public Facing SQL Server from 1 Site Only

Tags: sql-server, database, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, static-ip-address

Yes it is a public facing SQL Server.

I can connect to it from multiple locations and PCs without issue.

I have 1 location that can't. All other sites are running without issue all day.

I have tried through SSMS (i.e. 111.111.111.111\INSTANCE NAME with correct login) and returns error 26.

I feel like i have tried everything possible...i can access it in the same manor from my home PC, office PC, Library PC....

The ONLY difference i have come across is this location is setup with a static IP address.

Is it possible that the static IP is the issue?

Comment: Can you ping that IP from the machine that can't connect? It isn't going to be a problem that machine making the connection is a static IP. Is there a firewall on the PC preventing communication through whatever port you are using? (1433 is the default). There could be a number of things.

Comment: Yes, I can ping the servers IP. From what i can see just normal windows Firewall, no special security software. I have opened the SQL default firewall ports and temporarily turn off the firewall.

Comment: So what have you tried? A quick google search reveals a mountain of discussions on this topic. https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+error+26&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: This MSDN blog article describes how to troubleshoot error 26: SQL Protocols Team > SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 – Error Locating Server/Instance Specified: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/

Comment: @SeanLange - Tried everything in the top 10 search results from your link.

Comment: @RichardCL - Tried everything in that link

Comment: I do not think this is an issue from our server, as I have 50 other PCs connected to it on a continuous basis.  On client PC, all firewalls are off, and it was working up until a few days ago.  Apparently nothing has changed network wise since then.

Comment: I'd use Wireshark to monitor the network traffic and see what's happening to the response from the SQL Server Brower. The raw network traffic tells the truth.

Comment: @RichardCL I was able to run WireShark on both client PC and server.  
From the client PC i can see the outgoing UDP call from [local ip] [port ####] to [server ip] [port 1434] from the Server i do not see any incoming request.   On the server i have SQL Browser.exe allowed through the firewall and port 1434 opened up.   Would that mean their router is blocking that request?

Comment: If there's a router in between, particularly if it has a firewall, that's got to be a suspect. Do you have access to the router and the knowledge to monitor/configure it? Otherwise it may be a case of calling in a network specialist.

Comment: Also, if the router is doing NAT overloading (PAT), I think that might mess things up. Is the router connecting to a public network, or just connecting two private networks?

Comment: @RichardCL The router does have NAT enabled and is connecting to a public network.

Comment: NAT translates IP addresses and should be ok. NAT overloading (aka PAT) is where multiple IP addresses on internal network are translated to a single public IP address. This involves changing the port numbers and I think will prevent the connection to SQL Server.

Comment: You might need to use a VPN to tunnel the connection. Or why not do the easy thing and move the SQL Server into Azure? Or even have two copies: one on premises and the other in Azure? You can sync them using Azure SQL Data Sync: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync/

Comment: @RichardCL I will try some more things with the router since that is where I am thinking the issue is more and more.  As for the server setup, we currently do have one on premises and the other on our cloud server (not Azure) and it is being synced via the Microsoft Sync Framework. Which is how we initially discovered this issue when their data stopped syncing.